# How to add glyphicon to link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to replace the word "like" with a heart icon.

Basically, I am trying to add `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>` to the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Like', like_post_path(post), method: :post %>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
<%= link_to like_post_path(post), method: :post do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Basically, you should use the link_to version that accepts a block

Comment: It worked! I have to wait 10 minutes to accept this answer. But I will mark it as correct. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

**This is for you**

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></i> Like'.html_safe, like_post_path(post), method: :post %>
```